# É apropriado usar If-Else em uma função junto com Fetch?

Tags: javascript, funções, api, fetch

Estou criando uma função com um .fetch pra pegar dados do openweathermap.org, que por definição retorna em fahrenheit. É aceitável do ponto de vista Clean Code, que diz que a função deve fazer apenas uma coisa e ter poucas linhas, fazer um bloco If-Else pra controlar isso OU é mais apropriado fazer outra função com uma flag e que retorne a url no formado desejado e usa-la na requestCurrentWeather()?
Abaixo um exemplo de como fica a extensa função com If-Else.

```
let flagUnitsFormat= true;

const requestCurrentWeather = cityName => {
let URL_CURRENT_WEATHER = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${keyApiCurrent}`
    if(flagUnitsFormat) {
        fetch(`${URL_CURRENT_WEATHER}&units=metric`, {method:'get'})
        .then(response => {
            response.json()
            .then(result => { console.log(result)});
        })
        .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
    } else {
        fetch(URL_CURRENT_WEATHER, {method:'get'})
        .then(response => {
            response.json()
            .then(result => { console.log(result)});
        })
        .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem receita de bolo pronto. Criar uma função separada só para adicionar os argumentos na sua URL torna o seu código mais legível? Torna-o mais reutilizável? Tente entender qual a motivação para seguir a regra ao invés de simplesmente segui-la cegamente, talvez ela nem faça sentido no seu contexto.

O que eu vejo no seu código que faria sentido, seria evitar escrever a mesma lógica do `fetch` duas vezes. Esse também é um dos princípios da programação conhecido como *DRY*. Ao invés de usar um `if/else` para executar a requisição com ou sem os argumentos adicionais, eu utilizaria uma condição lógica apenas para gerar a URL de destino. Talvez você nem precise de uma condição lógica.

Exemplo:

```
let URL_CURRENT_WEATHER = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${keyApiCurrent}`
if (flagUnitsFormat) {
    URL_CURRENT_WEATHER += '&units=metric'
}
```

Mas talvez você queira tornar a sua função mais flexível, para poder enviar mais argumentos além de `units`. Sua função pode ser refatorada de diversas maneiras para se tornar mais robusta, se fizer sentido, eu pessoalmente receberia os argumentos da URL como parâmetro, e as concatenaria na URL

```
function requestCurrentWeather(cityName, args = {}) {
    let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${keyApiCurrent}`
    url += Object.keys(args).map(k => `&${k}=${args[k]}`).join('')
```

E é claro, a função também pode ser `async` para poder resolver promises de forma imperativa. Mas se tudo isso é em busca de código limpo, então o resultado final sempre é um pouco subjetivo, e cabe a você jugar se isso é apropriado para o seu código

```
async function requestCurrentWeather(cityName, args = {}) {
    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${keyApiCurrent}`
    const query = Object.keys(args).map(k => `&${k}=${args[k]}`).join('')

    const response = await fetch(url + query).then(r => r.json())
    console.log(response)
}

// exemplo de utilização:
requestCurrentWeather('curitiba', { units: 'metric' })
```

Comment: Segui teu conselho do primeiro exemplo e achei o resultado bastante satisfatório. A função ficou pequena e cumpre bem o propósito.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do @user204221 já diz bem sobre o conceito subjetivo de como deixar o código. Eu nem entraria tanto nesse conceito porque no seu caso é um simples `if` o problema.

Vamos pensar diferente, por que precisa de um `if`?
Porque dependendo do "flagUnitsFormat" eu preciso passar isso na URL.

Se a resposta for só essa, poderia apenas montar a URL com um condicional, porque o resto do código é igual, poderia simplificar dessa forma:

```js
var url = flagUnitsFormat
   ? `${URL_CURRENT_WEATHER}&units=metric`
   : URL_CURRENT_WEATHER;

fetch(url, {method:'get'})
   .then(response => {
         response.json()
   .then(result => { console.log(result)});
```

É apenas uma sugestão, mas veja que reforça a ideia da outra resposta, depende do ponto de vista, mas sempre pense mais simples: preciso de if? como removo esse código duplicado?

Às vezes depois de responder isso, o código já vai estar bom :)